# CSVLink generating HTML instead of CSV in `react-csv` npm package

Tags: reactjs, csv, next.js

I am trying to download a CSV file from the below data:

```
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";

headers = [
  { label: "First Name", key: "firstname" },
  { label: "Last Name", key: "lastname" },
  { label: "Email", key: "email" }
];

data = [
  { firstname: "Ahmed", lastname: "Tomi", email: "ah@smthing.co.com" },
  { firstname: "Raed", lastname: "Labes", email: "rl@smthing.co.com" },
  { firstname: "Yezzi", lastname: "Min l3b", email: "ymin@cocococo.com" }
];

<CSVLink data={data} headers={headers}>
  Download me
</CSVLink>;
```

When I click the `Download me` link, I get a file with `.csv` extension, but it contains the HTML of that page. If I use `CSVDownload` the correct CSV file is downloaded.

I am using Next.js. What additional thing should I add to `CSVLink` so I get the correct CSV data?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Are you sure you're not getting any errors? Could you provide a codesandbox (or similar) with the issue?

Comment: facing the same issue. still don't know why

Comment: i'm using windows 11 @juliomalves

Answer (score 2):

Just down grade to react-csv 2.0.3 version. It's solve the issue for me. I think this is happening after the release of 2.2.* version.

Comment: Yes, Same issue, same solution.

Answer (score 1):

using react-csv@2.2.2

I was able to replicate the issue on Next.js. I managed to solve the issue by adding a separator:

```
<CSVLink data={data} headers={headers} separator={","}>
    Export
</CSVLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Next.js. I wathced many videos and articles and I found the problem is the 2.2.2 version. In one of the videos the guy used 2.0.3 version so I decided to giv it a try and it's working perfectly.